# R: How to perform calculation by rows using data stored in defined columns?

Tags: r, apply

The example data is shown as below:

| id | a | b | n1 | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 40 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 20 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 20 | 40 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 10 | 20 |

I need to calculate score `k1` and `k2` in R.

Assuming C is a constant.

k1=(a/b)/(n1/n2+C)

k2=(a/b)/(n1+n2+C)

Because row3 is double-arm zero data, k1 and k2 will be `NA`. If k1 or k2 is NA, an alternative formula will be used:

k1=n1/(n1+n2)

k2=n2/(n1+n2)

What I did is using for loop to locate the exact value in every single cell. But it will be very slow when applied to a huge dataset. `apply` function seems to be a faster method. But I'm too naive to create a runnable function for `apply(data, 1, function)`. I don't know what kind of input should be given into `apply`. Is there any elegant and faster way to do this job except for the for loop? Thank you so much.

My code is pasted below:

```
k1 = c()
k2 = c()
C = 0.25

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  k1[i] = (data[i,"a"]/data[i,"b"])/(data[i,"n1"]/data[i,"n2"]+C)
  k2[i] = (data[i,"a"]/data[i,"b"])/(data[i,"n1"]+data[i,"n2"]+C)
  
  if (is.na(k1[i])){
    k1[i] = data[i,"n1"]/(data[i,"n1"]+data[i,"n2"])
  }
  
  if (is.na(k2[i])){
    k2[i] = data[i,"n2"]/(data[i,"n1"]+data[i,"n2"])
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the `mutate` function from the `dplyr` package?

Comment: Seems like it's just `df %>% mutate(k1 = ifelse(a == 0 & b == 0, n1/(n1 + n2), (a/b)/(n1/n2 + C)), k2 = ifelse(a == 0 & b == 0, n2/(n1 + n2), (a/b)/(n1 + n2 + C)))`, but be aware of the `Inf` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mutate()` function from `{dplyr}`:

```
# Calculate k1 and k2
data <- data %>% 
    # Perform calculation
    mutate(k1 = (a/b)/(n1/n2+C),                     # k1
           k2 = (a/b)/(n1+n2+C),                     # k2
           k1 = ifelse(is.na(k1), n1/(n1+n2), k1),   # Other formula for k1 if k1 is NA
           k2 = ifelse(is.na(k2), n2/(n1+n2), k2))   # Other formula for k2 if k2 is NA
```

This gives me the same as your code returned, but is more efficient:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
      a     b    n1    n2      k1       k2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     1    10    20   1.33    0.0331
2     2     2    20    40   1.33    0.0166
3     0     0    10    20   0.333   0.667 
4     1     0    20    40 Inf     Inf     
5     0     1    10    20   0       0
```